# Streaming data throughput issue with winsock

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I have client application on Windows 7 that receive streaming data from IP camera using Winsock socket API "recv". I am not able to get full 30 fps when stream throughput goes beyond 20Mbps. I have raised the priority of my application using Task manager to "High" though not able to set to "Real time". I have also disabled the Nagle algorithm of the streaming socket. When analyzed the socket packets captured via Wireshark found the 200 msec delayed Acks. I think these delayed Acks are main source of lower throughput and frame loss at camera side. Am I thinking right? How to avoid these 200 msec delayed Acks?
What are winsock high speed extension? Is it necessary to use these extension for such an application?

Comment: Disabling the Nagle algorithm is no way to increase throughput. Disabling delayed ACKs ditto. The way to get maximum throughput is to write as much as possible as fast as possible and to use large socket send and receive buffers. Post some code.

Comment: I suspect code/protocol issues too:(

Comment: By setting TcpAckFrequency to 1 and raising the priority of the process to high helped. Now i can capture stream arounf 40 Mbps. Still don't understand the Window Tcp/Ip stack strange behavior of delaying the Acks of received packets. [link](http://www.docke.org/news/how-to-disable-delayed-acks-in-windows/). Thanks all for their time and comments.